# How to create Windows User interface in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, interface, controls, taskbar

I want to create a windows interface in ASP.net which include Taskbar, Windows(have option:Maximum, Minimize) I m also attaching the screen shot what i want to do.

Is there is any 3rd party control???

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ExtJs for example!

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/desktop/desktop.html